# Can I run a flow in Power Automate from a button in a spreadsheet, without using VBA

Tags: excel, power-automate

I'm very new to Power Automate, so I may be going about this in completely the wrong way.

Currently I'm using a 'When a file is Created or Modified trigger'. But I need it to be a bit more manual than that. Users need to be able to be able to double check the information, and then manually fire off the flow.

Ideally, I'd like a button. But what I've learned is that the flow in question doesn't work with .xlsm files, so I've already had to move data out of file1.xlsm into file2.xlsx using Power Query, and then the Power Automate is able to select data from file2.xlsx. As an automated process, this was working ok. I could use a macro in file1.xlsm to open file2.xlsx, refresh the query, and the flow would automatically trigger.

But now I need to be able to manually open file2.xlsx, double check the data, and change it if need be, before firing off the flow.

I've played with the idea of using a button to somehow change the value in a cell (similar to a check box, but it doesn't seem to be an option with a button), and then use that as a trigger for the power automate (although I'm not sure if that is even possible).

I thought I'd ask here if anyone knows of any really obvious options I've not thought of. I feel like this should be a fairly standard excel / automate functionality, and I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you and/or the people who are going to use the flow have the Power Automate Premium, you can just copy the link of the flow and paste into simple shape in Excel.
[image]

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "the link of the flow"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could attack this.  The way you end up going is completely up to you.

#### Office Scripts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

Within this framework, you can add a button which then performs a specific function which does what you want and sets a value in a field.

[image: Button]

You would need to check the relevant range value to determine whether or not to continue executing the PA flow and then set the field back to another value that will then turn the trigger off for every other subsequent change by your user base.

Is that the best option?  Probably not but you asked about it so I wanted to give you some insight into what may be possible.

#### PowerAutomate Button

Rather than using the modified file trigger, why not just create a flow that is triggered with a button push (the `Manually trigger a flow` action)?

[image: Button Flow]

This allows for full control over running of the flow.  That button could be assigned to only yourself and therefore, only you would be able to run it.  If you wanted to assign it to others, you could do that as well.

Bottom line, this would be your button push.  You wouldn't do it from Excel though, you'd simply do it from PA.  It can also be easily accessed from the mobile app.

This, to me, would be the more obvious approach.

Comment: Thanks Skin. I’ve seen power automate buttons, but if it doesn’t allow me to then put the button into excel, it’s not much more useful than just having power automate up in the side bar (add in) and then pressing the play button for the flow. Interesting that I could have a list of buttons in this side bar though, I hadn’t realised the buttons would sit there, only saw that you could use them in Mobile apps. So I’ll look into that as an option.